# DataAnnotations MaxLength and StringLength for string[] or List<string>?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I am trying to figure out if there is a proper way to achieve this with DataAnnotations:

Have an array or List of strings where the maximum number of elements in the array or List is 2 items and where each string may only be, say 255 characters long. Will this work:

```
[MaxLength(2)]
[StringLength(255)]
public string[] StreetAddress { get; set; }
```

I would rather not have to make a new class just to hold a string `Value` property to constrain each string to 255 characters.

Comment: Can you do that with attributes alone?  Doubtful.  That said, there is a very good reason that DataAnnotations ships with the `IValidatableObject` interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own validation attribute by inheriting from Validation Attribute like described here: [How to: Customize Data Field Validation in the Data Model Using Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, deriving from ValidationAttribute.

[ListStringValidation(3, 128)]
Would validate that a List<string> had no more that 3 elements in the List, and that none of them were longer than 128 characters.

Comment: Just as a note, the documentation has since been moved here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx

Answer (score 6):

This is a custom attribute for list of strings:

```
public class StringLengthListAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public StringLengthListAttribute(int maximumLength)
        : base(maximumLength) { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is not List<string>)
            return false;

        foreach (var str in value as List<string>)
        {
            if (str.Length > MaximumLength || str.Length < MinimumLength)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```