# How to constraint length of strings within a list, using a Data Annotation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

In an Entity Framework data model, I have a list of strings:

`public List<string> Comments { get; set; }`

I'm trying to restrict the size of the strings within the above list. I wish to do this by using data annotations as all other restrictions are expressed that way throughout the model.

This is what I have tried:

```
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
```

The above code does does not work, as the StringLength constraint is applied to the list itself and not to the elements within. This results in the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbUnexpectedValidationException: An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'Comments' when invoking System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute.IsValid.
[...]
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'.
```

How can I constraint a string's length, in cases where the string is composed by a collection such as a list, using a data annotations?
One idea is that it might be possible to write a custom annotation -- that would be a valid answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746105/dataannotations-maxlength-and-stringlength-for-string-or-liststring

Comment: Entity Framework data model with list of strings? I don't think it's supported, do you?

Answer (score 0):

One option, although I don't feel it is very elegant is to create a new type that functions like the `string` type and decorate that with your annotations.

```
public class Comment
{
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 1)]
    private readonly string _value;

    public Comment(string value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Comment s)
    {
        return s.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator Comment(string s)
    {
        return new Comment(s);
    }
}
```

then your property would be updated to:

```
public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

You can use it like a `string` type:

```
var foo = new YourClass();
foo.Comments = new List<Comment>();
foo.Comments.Add("bar"); // note that it works *like* a string 

// the following is the equivalent, but just looks like a usual class initializer
foo.Comments.Add(new Comment("bar"));
```