# How do I get an input error rather than a smaller input string?

Tags: c#, .net

Let me point out that I started learning .NET / C# last week because of a new internship and that I'm so new that I don't fully understand the code yet. Things seem way more complex than Python/PHP/Javascript to me.

I'm currently doing this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1

The tutorial tells me to add [StringLength(50)] to my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then run the following commands in the command prompt:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MaxLengthOnNames
dotnet ef database update
```

After doing so, it says I should run the app and try to create a new student with more than 50 characters and it should prevent me from doing so. Rather than preventing me to input 50 characters, it will shorten the input to 50 characters. I would normally think of an if statement to check if the input is longer than 50 characters. However I'm sticking to the guide, but I'm getting unexpected results.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746105/dataannotations-maxlength-and-stringlength-for-string-or-liststring